# $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\frac{d\theta}{[(1-r)^2 + 2\pi^{-2}\theta^2]^p}} < \frac{1}{(1-r)^{2p-1}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{dt}{[1+2\pi^{-2}t^2]^p}}$

Tags: integration, inequality, hardy-spaces

I found this inequality from Duren's book Theory of Hp-spaces(2000) page 66. According to the book inequality should be true for $\frac{1}{2}\leq r < 1$ and $p>\frac{1}{2}$. I have tried to prove that

$$\frac{1}{[(1-r)^2 + 2\pi^{-2}\theta^2]^p} < \frac{1}{(1-r)^{2p-1}[1+2\pi^{-2}\theta^2]^p}$$

to get the inequality but I could not find the way. I was able to get

$$\frac{1}{[(1-r)^2 + 2\pi^{-2}\theta^2]^p} = \frac{1}{(1-r)^{2p}\left[1 + \frac{2\pi^{-2}\theta^2}{(1-r)^2}\right]^p} < \frac{1}{(1-r)^{2p}\left[1 + 2\pi^{-2}\theta^2\right]^p}$$
but I got stuck here.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to MSE! Could you re-edit your post to show what you have tried so we are able to properly see where you are stuck?

Comment: Hello and thank you for welcoming me, @PseudoLooped. I re-edited the post.

Comment: The first equality is good and then just change variables $t=\theta/(1-r)$ in the integral and majorize the integral that results with the same integral on the line

Comment: Oh yes now I get it. Thank you for the help @Conrad

Comment: Happy to be of help